Expected value of a random variable with random parameters
Intro to Probability, H. Pishro-Nik solves the below using law of total expectation (which I understand):

Suppose that the number of customers visiting a fast food restaurant
in a given day is N∼Poisson(λ). Assume that each customer purchases a
drink with probability $p$, independently from other customers and
independently from the value of $N$. Let $X$  be the number of customers who purchase drinks. Find $E[X]$.

I tried solving it using properties of expectation. X is a binomial random variable with $N$ trials and $p$ probability of success. Using the expectation of a binomial random variable:
$$E[X]=E[Np]$$
Since $p$ is a constant:
$$=pE[N]$$
And since $N$ is a poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, it has mean $\lambda$:
$$p\lambda$$
Is this correct?

The assumption that $X\sim \mathcal{B}(N,p)$ is wrong, $X∼\mathcal{P}(\lambda p)$
Rather you have that $X|N \sim \mathcal{B}(N,p)$. Using the law of total expectation:
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X|N]] = \mathbb{E}[pN] = p\mathbb{E}[N] = p \lambda$$
More in detail here
Binomial random variable with number of trials being a Poisson random variable.

Can you explain why the assumption that $X~B(N,p)$ is wrong?

Because it is a compound distribution, when you write $X \sim B(N,p)$ you supposed that N is fixed which is not the case. But when you study X conditionnally to N i.e. $X|N$ then N is fixed so you can write it as a binomial distribution.
